# why we will use prev.getResponseCode() in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

If give `String ResponseCode = prev.getResponseCode();` in beanshell assertion it's working good.

But if use `String ResponseCode = getResponseCode();` I am getting error, so what is the reason for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JMeter is a Java application , which is an Object Oriented language.

In the element you use, JMeter exposes few scripting objects described here:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_Assertion

One of them is SampleResult exposed under name « prev ».
This object is an instance of class :

- http://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html

By the way you should move to JSR223 Assertion using groovy.

Answer (score 1):

`prev` is a shorthand for **prev**iuos [SampleResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html), see the JavaDoc for all available methods and fields.

Depending on parent sampler type it might resolve into different classes, i.e. [HTTPSamplerResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/sampler/HTTPSampleResult.html) which may provide more useful methods.

Also if you look at the bottom of the Beanshell Assertion test element you will see some other pre-defined variables which you may find useful:

[image: JMeter Beanshell Assertion Variables]

As you can see there is already a `ResponseCode` variable which holds current sampler response code.

Check out [How to Use JMeter Assertions in Three Easy Steps](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-assertions-3-easy-steps) article for comprehensive information on different assertion types.